# Global name 'camera' is not defined in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

In this script :-

```
camera_port = 0
ramp_frames = 400
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port) 
def get_image():
  global camera
  retval, im = camera.read()
  return im

def Camera():
    global camera
    for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
     temp = get_image()
    print("Taking image...")
    camera_capture = get_image()
    file = "opencv.png"
    cv2.imwrite(file, camera_capture)
    del(camera)

def Sendmail():
    loop_value = 1
    while loop_value==1:
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen("https://google.com")
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print "Network currently down." 
            sleep(20)
        else:
            print "Up and running." 
            loop_value = 0
def Email():
    loop_value = 2
    while loop_value==2:
        try:
            Camera()
            Sendmail()
            yag = yagmail.SMTP('email',   'pass')
            yag.send('amitaagarwal565@gmail.com', subject = "This is    opencv.png", contents = 'opencv.png')
            print "done"
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print 'Retrying in 30 seconds'
            sleep(30)
        else:
            print 'Sent!'
            sleep(20)
            loop_value = 2
```

I get this error :-

What am I doing wrong. I have even defined camera globally, that to TWICE. Can somone please point out my mistake in the code? I use python 2.7 with Opencv module

```
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Servers.py", line 22, in Camera
    temp = get_image()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Servers.py", line 16, in get_image
    retval, im = camera.read()
NameError: global name 'camera' is not defined
```

*UPDATE*
Look above for updated code

Comment: You don't really need to pass `global camera` to the function in order to use it.

Comment: @Nf4r But still, it dosen't solve the problem

Comment: I do not see any error here. Is this the original code which you are using?

Comment: @HellfireCharchitPb: I notice that the line numbers in the error message do not correspond to the line numbers in your code. So, there is some more code! Also, notice that if you ever call `Camera()` you will delete the reference to `camera`(last line). From this point onward it should not be defined.

Comment: @M.Wymann There is some other code to, but I do not think that it will matter, however i will update it

Comment: @HellfireCharchitPb. If you ever call `Email()`, the following should happen. In the first iteration `loop_value == 2` the function `Camera()` is called which deletes `camera`. In the second iteration when the same call is encountered, `camera`is not defined anymore (as it was `del(camera)`). Maybe you should avoid the second iteration, by setting `loop_value` to something that is not 2.

Comment: @M.Wymann like maybe `loop_value ==1`

Comment: @M.Wymann Can you possibly give a more detailed answer? Perhaps not in a comment but in a actual answer? Because that is exactly what is happening, it all works out the first time, but in the second it gives out the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have defined `camera` outside the scope of your methods as well. What the `global` keyword does is tell Python that you will modify that variable which you defined externally. If you haven't, you get this 
error.

**EDIT**

I didn't notice that you had already declared `camera` externally. However, you delete the variable inside the `Camera()` method, which has pretty much the same effect when you try to modify the variable again.

**EDIT 2**

Now that I can see what your code really does and what you intend to do, I don't think you should be working with a global `camera` at all, but pass it as parameter instead. This should work:

```
camera_port = 0
ramp_frames = 400

def get_image(camera):
    retval, im = camera.read()
    return im

def Camera(camera):
    for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
        temp = get_image(camera)
    print("Taking image...")
    camera_capture = get_image(camera)
    file = "opencv.png"
    cv2.imwrite(file, camera_capture)

def Sendmail():
    loop_value = 1
    while loop_value==1:
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen("https://google.com")
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print "Network currently down." 
            sleep(20)
        else:
            print "Up and running." 
            loop_value = 0

def Email():
    loop_value = 2
    while loop_value==2:
        try:
            camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port) 
            Camera(camera)
            Sendmail()
            yag = yagmail.SMTP('email',   'pass')
            yag.send('amitaagarwal565@gmail.com', subject = "This is    opencv.png", contents = 'opencv.png')
            print "done"
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print 'Retrying in 30 seconds'
            sleep(30)
        else:
            print 'Sent!'
            sleep(20)
            loop_value = 2
```

Comment: You mean outside the functions?

Comment: Yes, but it's deleted inside `Camera`. I forgot to add this to my answer, sorry.

Comment: Oh yes. I missed that part. Good Catch (y)

Comment: @HellfireCharchitPb Yes, but I didn't notice you had already done that. I've updated my answer targetting the actual problem.

Comment: I get this error now `File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Servers.py", line 16, in get_image
    retval, im = camera.read()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: `camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port) ` can you confirm that it's returning what it's expecting ?

Comment: @MooingRawr It is correct and returning what I expect (double checked)

Comment: Yes, because you turned the `camera` variable into None (last line of `Camera` method) and then you try to call `read()` from it in `get_image`. I'm afraid I don't think I can help much further since I don't know what you expect to happen with the `camera` variable at the end of the `Camera()` method.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti I will redirect you to a form with detailed explanation, please spare some time. [link](https://codeplasma.com/2012/12/03/getting-webcam-images-with-python-and-opencv-2-for-real-this-time/)

Comment: @HellfireCharchitPb OK, I think I understand now. To me, it seems that you shouldn't be working with a global `camera` at all. Try instead passing it as a parameter to your methods. I'll update my answer with a suggestion that should work.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti I have to say that was really wise solution, thanks it works!